# insert items into mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Try to insert following into mysql in php, but don't know why it always return empty query. .   Also, when I use phpmyadmin to check table row, it shows 0 rows there.
Please help.

```
// Create a connection to the database via the following variables.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Check connection.
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
     {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }


// Insert items into database Inventory
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier,LastInvDate) VALUES ('Peaches', 22, 20, 100, 'TRUE', 'Tree Farms','20140430')");

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Apples', 36, 20, 150, 'TRUE', 'Tree Farms', '20140328')");

mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Paper Towels', 24, 20, 100, 'FALSE', 'Sysco', '20140326')");

mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Snickers', 55, 20, 100, 'FALSE', 'Candy Co', '20140429')");

mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Dish Soap', 17, 20, 100, 'FALSE', 'Clean Co', '20140320')");

mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Coffee', 29, 20, 100, 'FALSE', 'Coffee Co', '20140430')");

mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES ('Newspaper', 21, 20, 100, 'FALSE', 'The Tribune', '20140329')");


//close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: What happens when you try those queries directly against the database?

Comment: @LMayday If `Perishable` is bool, try `FALSE`/`TRUE` without quotes.

Comment: @LMayday If `LastInvDate` is `date`, try `'20140329'` with `-` `('2014-03-29')`

Comment: Don't Insert a lot of data , First insert one line, and if it works go to the next like that you will be able to find out whats wrong

Comment: after i add the error check statement, it shows Unknown column 'LastInvDate' in 'field list'..but I already has this column, and the name is enter correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query` returns `FALSE` if an error occurs, take an advantage of that and debug the problem. Besides, you only echo if an error occurs while connecting to the database, you proceed to query the data anyway as your code is now.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error();
    exit(); // You don't want to make the query occurr if you actually fail to connect.
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Inventory(ProductName, Quantity, MinStock, MaxStock, Perishable, Supplier, LastInvDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
// Using prepared statements is the way to go. HOWEVER I recommend using PDO, there you can use named parameters.
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("siiisss", "Peaches", 22, 20, 100, "TRUE", "Tree Farms", "20140430");

$result = $stmt->execute();
if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception($mysqli->error");
}
else
{
    echo "success.";
}
```

Comment: it shows Unknown column 'LastInvDate' in 'field list'

Comment: Meaning it's a typo or the column is simply missing from your database.

Comment: Try using different quotes.

Comment: You need to use regular quotes ' for string values. Replace them and make sure you're using them.

Comment: I edited the answer, now using prepared statements, take a look at it.